# How to insert id of some table into another in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im doing insert into 2 tables in first table im inserting this array

```
   array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["language_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["property_id"]=>
    int(82)
    ["option_id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["value_num"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

and in second one im inserting this array

```
array(2) {
["property_type_id"]=>
string(2) "21"
["alt_txt"]=>
string(7) "4666.45"}
```

and this is my function in controller for insert

```
    public function save_dynamic($data, $id)
{
    // Delete all
    $this->db->where('property_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('value !=', 'SKIP_ON_EMPTY');
    $this->db->delete('property_value'); 

    // Insert all
    $insert_batch = array();
    foreach($data as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(substr($key, 0, 6) == 'option')
        {
            $pos = strpos($key, '_');
            $option_id = substr($key, 6, $pos-6);
            $language_id = substr($key, $pos+1);

            $val_numeric = NULL;
            if( is_numeric($value) )
            {
                $val_numeric = intval($value);
            }

            $insert_arr = array('language_id' => $language_id,
                                'property_id' => $id,
                                'option_id' => $option_id,
                                'value' => $value,
                                'value_num' => $val_numeric);

            if($value != 'SKIP_ON_EMPTY')
                $insert_batch[] = $insert_arr;


        }
    }

                        $data=$this->input->post('data');
    if(count($insert_batch) > 0)
        $this->db->insert_batch('property_value', $insert_batch); 
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        $this->db->insert_batch('property_type_details', $data);
```

and here is how my tables looks like

```
Field Type
id int(11) NOT NULL
language_id int(11) NOT NULL
property_id int(11) NOT NULL
option_id int(11) NOT NULL
value text NULL
value_num int(11) NULL

Field Type
id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
property_id int(10) NULL
property_type_id int(10) NULL
alt_txt double(10,2) NULL
```

So what im want to do is to insert property_id also in second table together with second array

Answer (score 0):

use the codeigniter return `$this->db->insert_id()` or $get_id = `$this->db->insert_id`

Here is how i get id from another table:

```
public function addBanner() {
    $data = array('name' => $this->input->post('name'),'status' =>   $this->input->post('status'));
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->insert('banner');

    $banner_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    $data = array(
        'banner_id' => (int)$banner_id,
        'image' => $data_image['file_name'],
        'link' => $link
    );


    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->insert('banner_image');
    }
}

return $banner_id;
}
```

Comment: i have already try with $this->db->insert_id() its not work for me

Comment: its come array like 
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [property_type_id] => 22
            [alt_txt] => 1555.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [property_type_id] => 21
            [alt_txt] => 72523
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [property_id] => 32451
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function save_dynamic($data, $id)
{
    // Delete all
    $this->db->where('property_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('value !=', 'SKIP_ON_EMPTY');
    $this->db->delete('property_value'); 

    // Insert all
    $insert_batch = array();
    foreach($data as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(substr($key, 0, 6) == 'option')
        {
            $pos = strpos($key, '_');
            $option_id = substr($key, 6, $pos-6);
            $language_id = substr($key, $pos+1);

            $val_numeric = NULL;
            if( is_numeric($value) )
            {
                $val_numeric = intval($value);
            }

            $insert_arr = array('language_id' => $language_id,
                                'property_id' => $id,
                                'option_id' => $option_id,
                                'value' => $value,
                                'value_num' => $val_numeric);

            if($value != 'SKIP_ON_EMPTY')
                $insert_batch[] = $insert_arr;


        }
       $data=$this->input->post('data');
       $this->db->insert('property_value', $insert_batch);
       $data['property_id']=$this->db->insert_id();
       $this->db->insert('property_type_details', $data);
    }
 }
```

Comment: i have already try with $data['property_id']=$this->db->insert_id(); but when im using it its nothing gonna insert on tables